# split string with negative regex pattern

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

I want to split sting by non alphanumeric characters except a particular pattern .

Example :

```
string_1 = "section (ab) 5(a)"
string_2 = "section -bd, 6(1b)(2)"
string_3 = "section - ac - 12(c)"
string_4 = "Section (ab) 5(1a)(cf) (ad)"
string_5 = "section (ab) 5(a) test (ab) 5 6(ad)"
```

i want to split these strings in a way so that i can get bellow output

```
["section", "ab", "5(a)"]
["section", "bd", "6(1b)(2)"]
["section", "ac", "12(c)"]
["section", "ab", "5(1a)(cf)", "ad"]
["section", "ab", "5(a)", "test", "ab, "5", "6(ad)"]
```

To be more precise i want to split into every non-alphanumeric characters except this `\d+([\w\(\)]+)` pattern .

Comment: Are you unsure what the regex should look like? What have you tried?

Comment: @Chiperific , i'm not sure about regex , so what i've tried is `\W(?!(\d+([\w\(\)]+)))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```py
\d+[\w()]+|\w+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RCDo4K/1).

**Details**

- `\d+[\w()]+` - 1+ digits and then 1+ word or `(` or `)` chars
- `|` - or
- `\w+` - 1+ word chars.

In ElasticSearch, use

```js
"tokenizer": {
  "my_tokenizer": {
    "type": "pattern",
    "pattern": "\\d+[\\w()]+|\\w+",
    "group": 0
  }
}
```

Comment: i'm looking for a single regex and  don't want to use `findall`

Comment: @Aninda There is a *single* `r'\d+[\w()]+|\w+'` regex here. And if not `re.findall`, what method do you plan to use (and why restrict it to work only with some specific method)? Note that there is no way to use `re.split` here, because you cannot skip sequences of patterns with `re` regex. It is possible with PyPi `regex` module though.

Comment: @Aninda If you use the PyPi regex split approach, you will receive empty items in the output sometimes, see [the demo](https://tio.run/##ZU@xasMwFNz9FYcWvxerASekQyEdA6FLIUOHOIMty6kgsYQkqAr9d1cJIRCyPN7dPe7uud/4bcflNJmzsz7C66NORYjejMeANfZl0CoaO4LajrGilkuJO/nS9RKvVHdMi0cBrcqjXpDKvNg9mtQtkxo4w56FFE8RiDrEG8z2l6tD4VPuc@03V/bszEmTL5u@2jc/xIeKZruP7SfTbMN/zVdVcjFYjwQz4vbOWwG4vEVCkhDrdyHh0zy4k4mUGDxN/w). I'd rather stick to `re.findall`.

Comment: i need this regex pattern because i'll use them with Elasticsearch (pattern tokenizer) , so no `re.findall` for me . though your regex help me lot, thankx

Answer (score 1):

It can be achieved in this regex inside `findall` using:

```
\b\w+(?:\([^)]*\))*
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZVPPpZ/3)

**Code:**

```
>>> import re
>>> reg = re.compile(r'\b\w+(?:\([^)]*\))*')
>>> arr = ['section (ab) 5(a)', 'section -bd, 6(1b)(2)', 'section - ac - 12(c)', 'Section (ab) 5(1a)(cf) (ad)', 'section (ab) 5(a) test (ab) 5 6(ad)']
>>> for el in arr:
...     print ( reg.findall(el) )
...
['section', 'ab', '5(a)']
['section', 'bd', '6(1b)(2)']
['section', 'ac', '12(c)']
['Section', 'ab', '5(1a)(cf)', 'ad']
['section', 'ab', '5(a)', 'test', 'ab', '5', '6(ad)']
```

Comment: but it 's not removing `()` from  string_1 . the output of  `string_1` should be `["section", "ab", "5(a)"]` instead of `['section', '(ab)', '5(a)']`

Comment: this one is applicable only for example strings ,but it's not working  with `section (ab) 5(a) test (ab) 5` or  `Section (ab) 5(1a)(cf) (ad)` .sorry i think i should have added more example string .  i've updated my question with more examples

Comment: @Aninda: Did this work out or you only need a split regex?

Comment: actually i need a split regex for Elasticsearch (pattern tokenizer) , so `findall` isn't a option for me . your `[()]?[^\w()]+?[()]?` regex helped me a lot ,thank you

Comment: oh then you should have tagged it with `Elasticsearch` instead of `python` or `python3` to get even better answer